# UIWebView with HTML 5 video autoplay

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, video

I have a problem with the autoplay, I used this two lines:

```
[webView setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
self.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
```

It works perfectly, but when I have multiple `<video>` on my web view, by using a slide system, all videos are launched, but I want to run the video when this on is displayed, so the others videos gonna launch when we're sliding on.

Exemple without JS:

```
    <section class="main-slider">
    <div class="item video">
        <!--poster="img/loading.gif"-->
        <video class="slide-video slide-media" autoplay muted playsinline preload="metadata">
            <source src="video/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <p class="caption"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item video">
        <video class="slide-video slide-media" autoplay muted playsinline preload="metadata">
            <source src="video/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <p class="caption"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item video">
        <video class="slide-video slide-media" autoplay muted playsinline preload="metadata">
            <source src="video/video3.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <p class="caption"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item video">
        <video class="slide-video slide-media" autoplay muted playsinline preload="metadata">
            <source src="video/video4.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <p class="caption"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item video">
        <video class="slide-video slide-media" autoplay muted playsinline preload="metadata">
            <source src="video/video5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <p class="caption"></p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're gonna use javascript and judge the frame:

```js
<script>
    function playVideo(el) {
        var windowHeight = jQuery( window ).height();
        $(el).each(function(){
            var thisPos = $(this).offset().top;

            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (topOfWindow + windowHeight - 200 > thisPos ){
                //play your video in here
            }
        });
    }

    $(window).scroll(function() {
            playVideo('.video_class_name');
    });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

hope it will help you

Comment: We can't manage it from the uiwebview ? Its the code for the page

Comment: It's for a carousel view